# VBA autofilter returns incomplete list

Tags: vba, excel, filter, autofilter

I am trying to filter a sheet based on a cell value in another sheet. The corresponding value is a name in column h of my second sheet.

At present It filters the data but only returns 1 row of data relating to the `filter_val` despite there being 9 rows of data.

```
   Sub filter_DMA_2()             '' will be set to the combobox when that's figured out

    Dim filter_val As String
    Dim filter_range As Range
    Dim Lrow As Long

    Set Billed_xls = Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users")
    With Billed_xls
        Lrow = .Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    'Set filter_range = Billed_xls.Sheets("Non Household Metered Users").Range("h:v")
    Set filter_range = Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users").Range("a2:v2" & Lrow)
    'End With

    filter_val = Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool_v1.xlsm").Worksheets("DMA list").Range("a1").Value

    With filter_range
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=filter_val '.Value
    End With

    End Sub
```

Any idea how to fix this so it returns all 9 rows of data?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any blank cells in column a of the filter range? Are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in the values that aren't being included in the filter?

Comment: Hi @Rory I have trimmed the data, but there are some blank cells in the list. It seems it is only selecting the first row in the sheet regardless of what `filter_val` is set too. I filled in the blanks with a value and this had no effect on the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your `Lrow` calculation is thrown by an existing filter - clear that first:

```
Sub filter_DMA_2()             '' will be set to the combobox when that's figured out

    Dim filter_val            As String
    Dim filter_range          As Range
    Dim Lrow                  As Long

    Set Billed_xls = Workbooks("Copy of SWR1304 (Future Development Risk Assessment) Strathaven.xls").Sheets("Non Household Metered Users")
    With Billed_xls
        ' clear any existing filter to get accurate row count
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Lrow = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set filter_range = .Range("a2:v2" & Lrow)
    End With

    filter_val = Workbooks("DMA_metered_tool_v1.xlsm").Worksheets("DMA list").Range("a1").Value

    filter_range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=filter_val 

End Sub
```

The wrong column was being referred to before for `filter_range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=filter_val`. this has been corrected and now the code runs perfectly.

Comment: Cheers @Rory, this doesn't change the result and the `Lrow` value (7740) is correct for this sheet.

Comment: Then I'd have to assume that the other rows don't exactly match the filter. Just as a test, what if you use: `filter_range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & filter_val & "*"` - do you then see the additional rows?

Comment: Hmm this is a little odd. The filter value is copied and pasted from the list a  a test and your addition of `"*"` again returns the same result. In addition I've noticed that the `Lrow .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is not properly qualified despite using `With Billed_xls` as when I do not have that sheet selected it returns  runtime error.1004.

Comment: Sorry - I overlooked a full stop before the `Rows.Count` - I have amended the code now. If it still doesn't work, can you put the workbook somewhere for me to have a look at?

Comment: Great, I'd been staring at that for ages. Pesky little '.'. Now when it's re-run it filters the data in some way but it is unclear how. Some rows are filtered away but multiple instances of some of the names in that column and some blanks remain. Where would you recommend me putting the workbook? Most sharing sites are blocked on this server.

Comment: Just to check, you are filtering on column **E**, not column H as you said in your original question?

Comment: Ah Ha, typical it would be a typo. Thanks ever so much for your help! Another personI have changed the code to `filter_range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=filter_val` and it now works. I will edit your answer to reflect this.